# Java EE plugin for Eclipse 3.4

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee

I started learning Java EE recently. Hence I want to create Java EE projects through eclipse IDE.
I downloaded the eclipse IDE for Java EE developers. I am using eclipse 3.4.2. But still I do not get the option to create a Java EE project in eclipse.

I googled a lot but could not find a proper Java EE plugin for eclipse IDE. Also, I came to know about a plugin called "MyEclipse" which can be used to create Java EE projects in eclipse. But I am not able to find from where I can download this plugin.

Comment: This is another reason why I don't like Eclipse.  The plug-in architecture allows you to plug in all sorts of things; the bad news is that everything is a plug-in.  There's little that's built-in and seamless, like IntelliJ.

Comment: Note that J2EE is outdated and upgraded to Java EE over 4 years ago. You might want to review if your books/tutorials are recent/decent enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can download MyEclipse from [here](http://www.myeclipseide.com/). There is a free 30 day trial. But after that, you will have to buy an annual license.

You should get the option of creating JavaEE projects in your Eclipse 3.4.2 though. Did you downloaded the 3.4.2 JavaEE distribution? Or installed the plugins manually? I would recommend you to download the JavaEE full distribution. It will save you a couple of headaches.

Comment: I do not want to download MyEclipse again. As mentioned above, I have already downloaded Eclipse JavaEE distribution. What you mean by JavaEE full distribution??

Answer (score 0):

It's called *Dynamic Web Project*, not *J2EE Project* or so.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse for Java EE allows you to create a number of different projects that could be considered Java EE and/or J2EE projects.

If you are creating a web application, you should create a Dynamic Web Project.

There is also an EJB Project, an Application Client Project, a Connector Project and an Enterprise Application Project.

You can find out more about these projects in the [Eclipse documentation for Ganymede](http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.wst.doc.user/topics/overview.html) (the moonish name of Eclipse 3.4).

You may want to consider upgrading to Eclipse 3.6 for Java EE developers, too.  It is the 'current release'. It is called Helios.